# FireBreath multiple MIMETypes

Tags: macos, firebreath

How to add multiple MIMETypes to my FireBreath plugin  and how would the plugin respond to multiple MIMETypes. I have tried adding an additional string in Pluginconfig.cmake to **set(FBSTRING_MIMEType "application/x-testplugin" "application/x-test-plugin")** and ran prepmac script which failed. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MULTIMIME_NOTES.txt](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/examples/FBTestPlugin/MULTIMIME_NOTES.txt) in the FireBreath repo:

```
Modified original FBTestPlugin as follows to support multiple mimetypes
in a single codebase:

1.  Edit PluginConfig.cmake, add multiple entries for the following
    entries: FBSTRING_MIMEType, ACTIVEX_PROGID, FBControl_GUID, and
    FBSTRING_PluginDescription.  Make sure that you provide unique values for
    all entries, including the GUIDs in FBControl_GUID.

2.  Edit Factory.cpp, modify PluginFactory::createPlugin() and add code
    to check mimetype and create the appropriate object.  Also add
    "mimetype" as a parameter to
    "boost::make_shared<FBTestPlugin>(mimetype)".  The new code can construct
    the "standard" FBTestPlugin plugin, or a new "SimpleMath" plugin from
    either the FBTestPlugin or FBTestMathPlugin C++ objects.

3.  In FBTestPlugin.h, modify the FBTestPlugin constructor to take
    "const std::string& mimetype" as an argument.  Add "std::string
    m_mimetype;" as a private variable to FBTestPlugin.

4.  In FBTestPlugin.cpp, modify the FBTestPlugin constructor to take
    "const std::string& mimetype" as an argument and to set m_mimetype from
    the mimetype parameter.  Modify createJSAPI() to return 
    "boost::make_shared<SimpleMathAPI>(m_host)"
    instead of 
        "boost::make_shared<FBTestPluginAPI>(FB::ptr_cast<FBTestPlugin>(shared_from_this()), m_host)"
    depending on the mimetype.  Include "SimpleMath.h".
    Modify the plugin text in the drawing code depending on the mimetype for visual feedback to user.

5.  Modify SimpleMathAPI.h and SimpleMathAPI.cpp to add "self" property
    and "GetSelf()" method, both of which return shared_from_this().

6.  Copy FBTestPlugin.* to FBTestMathPlugin.* and change object name.
    Simplify FBTestMathPlugin by removing the LeakFinder.  Modify
    createJSAPI() to return only the SimpleMathAPI object.  Modify the
    plugin text in the drawing code for visual feedback to user.

7.  Modified test code in test.html to test multiple mimetypes.  Create
    three plugins, and test math functions using all three.
```